# Is it possible to rename channels in animation?

Tags: animation

Is it possible to rename channels in animation? For example, I want to change "Position(Color Ramp Element)" to "Position(Another name)"

I know how to change animation name or action name, but I want to change channel name, because there are so many channels with the same name.

[image]

Comment: Double click on the name and it should highlight it allowing you to change it.  Isn't that working in your case? You can't change the field you currently have highlighted -- that's the object the animation is attached to.

Comment: At present (v3.0.1) you can rename objects like "Suzanne" above.  You can rename the Node Tree "Geometry Nodes.001", but the channels appear to be read-only?